# Event Based Activation not working in desktop window

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I had configure my add-in for **event based activation** using the following link :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/autolaunch?tabs=xmlmanifest

My addin is working fine in **localhost server** and **desktop(windows)**. But when I had deployed my project on **server** after that it's not working in **desktop**. The uploaded version is **only working in my desktop** not any **one else**. I had attached the screenshot of error below.

[image: Addin Unavailable]

My manifest code is below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OfficeApp xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1" xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0" xmlns:mailappor="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="MailApp">
   <Id>37cba818-c575-4ac2-85fe-332d9eae8213</Id>
   <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
   <ProviderName>Event Test</ProviderName>
   <DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
   <DisplayName DefaultValue="Test-outlook-addin" />
   <Description DefaultValue="A template to get started." />
   <IconUrl DefaultValue="https://event-test.net/assets/icon-64.png" />
   <HighResolutionIconUrl DefaultValue="https://event-test.net/assets/icon-128.png" />
   <SupportUrl DefaultValue="https://www.contoso.com/help" />
   <AppDomains>
      <AppDomain>https://event-test.net</AppDomain>
   </AppDomains>
   <Hosts>
      <Host Name="Mailbox" />
   </Hosts>
   <Requirements>
      <Sets>
         <Set Name="Mailbox" MinVersion="1.1" />
      </Sets>
   </Requirements>
   <FormSettings>
      <Form xsi:type="ItemRead">
         <DesktopSettings>
            <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://event-test.net/taskpane.html" />
            <RequestedHeight>250</RequestedHeight>
         </DesktopSettings>
      </Form>
   </FormSettings>
   <Permissions>ReadWriteMailbox</Permissions>
   <Rule xsi:type="RuleCollection" Mode="Or">
      <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Message" FormType="Edit" />
      <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Appointment" FormType="Edit" />
      <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Message" FormType="Read" />
      <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Appointment" FormType="Read" />
   </Rule>
   <DisableEntityHighlighting>false</DisableEntityHighlighting>
   <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
      <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.1" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_1">
         <Requirements>
            <bt:Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.10">
               <bt:Set Name="Mailbox" />
            </bt:Sets>
         </Requirements>
         <Hosts>
            <Host xsi:type="MailHost">
               <!--  Event-based activation happens in a lightweight runtime. -->
               <Runtimes>
                  <!--  HTML file including reference to or inline JavaScript event handlers.
                 This is used by Outlook on the web and Outlook on the new Mac UI.  -->
                  <Runtime resid="WebViewRuntime.Url">
                     <!--  JavaScript file containing event handlers. This is used by Outlook on Windows.  -->
                     <Override type="javascript" resid="JSRuntime.Url" />
                  </Runtime>
               </Runtimes>
               <DesktopFormFactor>
                  <FunctionFile resid="Commands.Url" />
                  <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="AppointmentOrganizerCommandSurface">
                     <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
                        <Group id="msgReadGroup">
                           <Label resid="GroupLabel" />
                           <!--  this control used for taskpane   -->
                           <Control xsi:type="Button" id="msgReadOpenPaneButton">
                              <Label resid="TaskpaneButton.Label" />
                              <Supertip>
                                 <Title resid="TaskpaneButton.Label" />
                                 <Description resid="TaskpaneButton.Tooltip" />
                              </Supertip>
                              <Icon>
                                 <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon.16x16" />
                                 <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32x32" />
                                 <bt:Image size="80" resid="Icon.80x80" />
                              </Icon>
                              <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                                 <SourceLocation resid="Taskpane.Url" />
                              </Action>
                           </Control>
                           <!--  this control used for syncronize the data  -->
                           <Control xsi:type="Button" id="msgReadOpenPaneButton1">
                              <Label resid="TaskpaneSyncButton.Label" />
                              <Supertip>
                                 <Title resid="TaskpaneSyncButton.Label" />
                                 <Description resid="TaskpaneSyncButton.Tooltip" />
                              </Supertip>
                              <Icon>
                                 <bt:Image size="16" resid="sync_Icon.16x16" />
                                 <bt:Image size="32" resid="sync_Icon.32x32" />
                                 <bt:Image size="64" resid="sync_Icon.64x64" />
                                 <bt:Image size="80" resid="sync_Icon.80x80" />
                              </Icon>
                              <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                                 <SourceLocation resid="TaskpaneSyncButton.Url" />
                              </Action>
                           </Control>
                        </Group>
                     </OfficeTab>
                  </ExtensionPoint>
                  <!--  Can configure other command surface extension points for add-in command support.  -->
                  <!--  Enable launching the add-in on the included events.  -->
                  <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="LaunchEvent">
                     <LaunchEvents>
                        <LaunchEvent Type="OnAppointmentSend" FunctionName="onAppointmentSendHandler" SendMode="PromptUser" />
                     </LaunchEvents>
                     <!--  Identifies the runtime to be used (also referenced by the Runtime element).  -->
                     <SourceLocation resid="WebViewRuntime.Url" />
                  </ExtensionPoint>
               </DesktopFormFactor>
            </Host>
         </Hosts>
         <Resources>
            <bt:Images>
               <bt:Image id="Icon.16x16" DefaultValue="https://event-test.net/assets/icon-16.png" />
               <bt:Image id="Icon.32x32" DefaultValue="https://event-test.net/assets/icon-32.png" />
               <bt:Image id="Icon.64x64" DefaultValue="https://event-test.net/assets/icon-64.png" />
               <bt:Image id="Icon.80x80" DefaultValue="https://event-test.net/assets/icon-80.png" />
               <bt:Image id="sync_Icon.16x16" DefaultValue="https://event-test.net/assets/sync-icon-16.png" />
               <bt:Image id="sync_Icon.32x32" DefaultValue="https://event-test.net/assets/sync-icon-32.png" />
               <bt:Image id="sync_Icon.64x64" DefaultValue="https://event-test.net/assets/sync-icon-64.png" />
               <bt:Image id="sync_Icon.80x80" DefaultValue="https://event-test.net/assets/sync-icon-80.png" />
            </bt:Images>
            <bt:Urls>
               <bt:Url id="Commands.Url" DefaultValue="https://event-test.net/commands.html" />
               <bt:Url id="Taskpane.Url" DefaultValue="https://event-test.net/taskpane.html" />
               <bt:Url id="TaskpaneSyncButton.Url" DefaultValue="https://event-test.net/taskpane.html?type=syncronization" />
               <bt:Url id="WebViewRuntime.Url" DefaultValue="https://event-test.net/commands.html" />
               <!--  Entry needed for Outlook on Windows.  -->
               <bt:Url id="JSRuntime.Url" DefaultValue="https://event-test.net/launchevent.js?t=1682675486662" />
            </bt:Urls>
            <bt:ShortStrings>
               <bt:String id="ActionButton.Label" DefaultValue="Perform an action" />
               <bt:String id="GroupLabel" DefaultValue="Event-Test" />
               <bt:String id="TaskpaneButton.Label" DefaultValue="Event-Test" />
               <bt:String id="TaskpaneSyncButton.Label" DefaultValue="Sync" />
            </bt:ShortStrings>
            <bt:LongStrings>
               <bt:String id="TaskpaneButton.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Open Event-Test Taskpane" />
               <bt:String id="TaskpaneSyncButton.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Synchronization data from server" />
            </bt:LongStrings>
         </Resources>
      </VersionOverrides>
   </VersionOverrides>
</OfficeApp>
```

Let me know if any other **file's code** is required?
I don't know why it's not working in **desktop**.

can anyone guide me on this problem?

[image: Minimum for onAppoinmentSend Event][image]

Answer (score 1):

Verify that your event-handling JavaScript file referenced by the Outlook client on Windows calls `Office.actions.associate`. This ensures that the event handler name specified in the manifest's `<LaunchEvent>` element is mapped to its JavaScript counterpart.

If your event-based add-in has only one JavaScript file referenced by Outlook on the web, Windows, and Mac, it's recommended to check on which platform the add-in is running to determine when to call `Office.actions.associate`, as shown in the following code:

```
if (Office.context.platform === Office.PlatformType.PC || Office.context.platform == null) {
  Office.actions.associate("onAppointmentSendHandler", onAppointmentSendHandler);
}
```

Based on my experience sometimes helps to remove the check (if) and leave only `Office.actions.associate` calls for the supported events.

Read more about that in the [Configure your Outlook add-in for event-based activation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/autolaunch?tabs=xmlmanifest) article.

Comment: How can we verify that window calls Office.actions.associate in production manifest?

Comment: The call is made from the JS file, not manifest.

Comment: Okay, but we have hosted the project on a server. Now I'm not able to debug the JS file.

Comment: You need to replace the file on the server and then clean the cached files on the client if you want to get results immediately. Otherwise, you need to wait until the updated file will be requested by the client (web browser instance where the add-in is running).

Comment: is there a version issue? I used version 1.10 under the VersionOverridesV1_1 and OnAppointmentSend requires a 1.12 version as per his document. I have attached the image of the version I used and the required version. can you please suggest to me which version i had to use in the project for onAppoinmentEvent?

Comment: It depends on the host application - whether it supports the required version (1.12). Are you sure that your host application version supports 1.12?

Comment: I don't know. Can we check that by code?

Comment: You can use the [isSetSupported](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.requirementsetsupport?view=common-js-preview#office-office-requirementsetsupport-issetsupported-member(1)) function for that.

Comment: @YadavShiv, can you confirm your JS file was successfully downloaded and cached by Outlook? The file will be located at a path with the following format:
%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Wef\{[Outlook profile GUID]}\[Outlook mail account encoding]\Javascript\[Add-in ID]_[Add-in Version]_[locale]\bundle.js

More information here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/autolaunch?tabs=xmlmanifest